# Including Worksheet Function into .Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace a simple "copy/paste" portion in my macro.  The updated code currently looks like this:

```
Sub Daily()

Dim X As Long
X = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(range("Reported_day"), Worksheets("Averages").Rows("3:3"), Worksheets("Averages").Rows("2:2"))

Sheets("Cost").Range("Tons").Value = Sheets("Averages").Range("4, X").Value
```

The above lines are to replace:

```
X = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Range("Reported_day"), Worksheets("Daily Avgs (year)").Rows("3:3"), Worksheets("Avgerages").Rows("2:2"))
Sheets("Cost").Range("Tons").Copy
Sheets("Averages").Cells(4, X).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The specific portion of the script returning the 1004 error is the .Range("4, X").Value.

Is there a way I can include the Worksheet Function into the range?  The 1004 Error is an "Application defined or object defined error." I feel like an Array would solve my problem, but I am not sure.  There is probably something simple I am missing, as I am quite new to VBA.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Range("4, X")` is not correct. If you're trying to use a variable, you need to have it outside of any quotation marks. In this case, neither the 4 or the X should be in quotation marks. And you should use `Cells` not `Range`. Like `Cells(4, X)`

Comment: I'm also noticing that between the original code and the new code, the destination and sources are being flipped. `Sheets("Cost").Range("Tons")` was the copy source originally, but now it has become the destination. Is this intended?

Comment: You were correct, I did have the the copy source flipped.  However, this was not the issue that was causing the error.  I included Cells(4, X), which has fixed the error message.  Unfortunately, this hasn't solved my problem.  Now, when the macro is used, only the first value in the column that is copied is pasted into the destination.

Comment: If you want cells to be affected, your range object has to include those cells. Try using functions like [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to stretch your `Cells(4,X)` to include all of the cells you wish to change. I'm not sure what `Range("Tons")` is, but you will want to make sure it includes all the cells you are trying to get data from. Ideally, they should be the same size.

Comment: An easy way to make sure they're the same size is to do something like `Sheets("Averages").Cells(4, X).Resize(Sheets("Cost").Range("Tons").Rows.Count)`

Answer (score 0):

Updated script to include the following lines:

```
    Dim X As Integer
X = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Range("Reported_day"), Worksheets("Averages ").Rows("3:3"), Worksheets("Averages").Rows("2:2"))

Sheets("Averages").Cells(4, X).Resize(Sheets(" Cost").Range("Tons").Rows.Count).Value = Sheets("Cost").Range("Tons").Value
```

With some editing to the Excel spreadsheet itself, I was able to get the cells to properly update.  This significantly sped up the macro.  Thank you for those who commented, your input was extremely helpful.